# Passing query strings with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've been googling for two hours now, can't find the answer. Hope you guys can help me out.

The following is part of a refresh script in jQuery. I'm using this code in *index.php*:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

// UPDATE TYPES
function typeUpdate() {
    jQuery.get("script.php"), function(data) {
        jQuery('#heroTypes').html(data);
    });
    window.setTimeout("typeUpdate();", 500);
};
</script>
```

That *script.php* contains a SQL command that gets information and updates a div in *index.php*. It works perfectly, but the thing is that now I need to pass a query string to that file. I tried doing like this but it won't work:

```
jQuery.get("script.php?s=<? $querySetup ?>"), function(data) {
```

**$querySetup** is the php variable that gets the query string. If I try to send it manually (for instance "script.php?s=53") it doesn't work either. Would **really** appreciate help here, is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have a redundant round bracket ")" in jQuery.get("script.php"**)**

Comment: What about such code `jQuery('#heroTypes').load("script.php?s=53");` Does it work?

Comment: Does the $querySetup catch the complete query string or just a get value ($_GET['s'])? Try urldecode as well.

Comment: The extra bracket is just a mistake by me when pasting this post.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, I don't think so. What line should I replace it with?

Comment: @Ragnar, $querySetup = $_GET["s"];

Comment: Don't think so means you tried and it doesn't work, or you didn't try? Replace all this block: `jQuery.get("script.php"), function(data) { jQuery('#heroTypes').html(data); });`

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, mostly because that I missed a ")" from your code. Works, thanks a lot! Very embarassing that I couldn't figure out that myself. But now it won't update automatically, how do I fix that? It's not that big of a deal really, but I'd like to know anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming `$querySetup` has been validated as safe to use)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var heroTypes = $('#heroTypes');
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        $.get('script.php', { s: "<?php echo $querySetup ?>" }, function(data) {
            heroTypes.html(data);
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

I hope your web server and database like getting hit twice a second.

I'm also concerned about this `$querySetup` variable. You realise in the context of `index.php`, this will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can't get it to work though. And by the way, I'm just using that interval for the moment.

Comment: You'll have to define *"can't get it to work"*. Are you getting anything in the error console? I'm pretty certain by now that you don't want to use `$querySetup` at this point too. What is the value you want to pass to `script.php` from `index.php` and where does it come from?

Comment: The $querySetup is a query string (looks like "username1108131343"). It sends the "username1108131343" to script.php where the script uses SQL to select a value in a table where the name of the table is the query string. I don't get any errors, nothing happens when the refresh script is updating.

Comment: @Cheezen I assumed from your question that `$querySetup` was an integer. I've removed the integer cast from my answer, try it now. BTW, allowing the table name to be passed as a query var is a *very* bad idea

Comment: Your code works as well, did you change anything more than the integer cast? Removed it myself with your previous code but wouldn't work.

Comment: @Cheezen Nope. Looking back through my edit history, all that is removed is `(int)`

Comment: And yeah, I know it may be a bad idea, but I don't know how to do it in any other way. My table contains 90 rows of elements with 5 columns of information used in a drag'n'drop container. I use the table to give them a sorting ID to save their positions, I'm using the sortable plugin as well to order them. And I want to have multiple of these tables to create different combinations. Lousy explanation, right? =) Maybe I can do it in a better way, if you know any easier method I'd like to know ;)

Comment: Oh, then it's my bad. Guess it's because I haven't slept for 27h.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your JavaScript syntax errors, you are not printing the PHP variable:

```
<? $querySetup ?>
```

You probably want one of these:

```
<? echo $querySetup ?>
<?=$querySetup ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<?= $querySetup ?>` instead of `<? $querySetup ?>`